# weight calculator

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to create a weight calculator in qt designer, I want to add some function on it but I can't, could your check it, please.

it's my homepage ui code:
my ui files : [google link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R05ZZ8snuSJtSoOCMSKBDS_lGmW8-JCF/view?usp=sharing)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainPage(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__()
        loadUi('Homepage.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.retrieveText)

    def takeText(self):
        x = self.plainTextEdit_2.currentText()
        self.textEdit.setText(x)


    def retrieveText(self):

        number=self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        number=float(number) * my below fuction
        self.textEdit.setText(str(number))


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
widget=MainPage()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and I want to add some function on it:

```
gender=input("If Man, please type M or if women type W: ")
heigh=int(input("Whats your heigh: "))
if(gender=="M"):
    r=int(((heigh*4/2.54)-128)*0.453)
    print("Your ideal weight: " + str(r))

elif(gender=="W"):
    r=int(((heigh*3.5/2.54)-108)*0.453)
    print("Your ideal weight: "+str(r))
```

user type the gender (M or W) in first text box and heigh in second textbox and when click on result button we can see resualt in last box

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work? Please, take a look at the following guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I find it and it was simple :)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class MainPage(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainPage, self).__init__()
        loadUi('HomePage.ui', self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.takeText)
        self.fillCombobox()

    def fillCombobox(self):
        gender = ["M", "W"]
        self.comboBox.addItems(gender)

    def takeText(self):
        gender = self.comboBox.currentText()
        heigh = int(self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText())
        if gender == "M":
            r = int(((heigh * 4 / 2.54) - 128) * 0.453)
        elif gender == "W":
            r = int(((heigh * 3.5 / 2.54) - 108) * 0.453)

        self.textEdit.setText(str(r))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget=MainPage()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```